# WPF C# - Loading MySQL Query into DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I am attempting to build a simple application that allows me to interact with a MySQL database I have set up. I can add records just fine; however, I cannot get them to display. I am simply presented with a blank datagrid control.

It could be something simple, but I have tried different approaches, searched online, and messed with it longer than I should have - to no avail. I have a feeling the issue might lie in my lack of understanding the DataGrid control. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

The Select method from the Database Connection class:

```
 public DataTable Select(string tableName)
    {

        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        this.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);


        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        this.Close();
        return dataSet.Tables[0]; 


    }
```

The following is a portion of the code for the window (called View) containing the datagrid. The table name is passed to it from the main window upon the click of a button.

```
 public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public View(string table)
    {
        this.table = table;
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void windowLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseConnection myConnection = new DatabaseConnection();

        dataGrid.DataContext = myConnection.Select(table).DefaultView;
```

}

Comment: have you verified that your Select method returns a datatable with the records you expect ?  Also, you should consider naming your method something other than Select, which is a keyword (in lambda expressions, for example)

Comment: Thanks, what would be a way to verify the contents of the datatable?

Comment: Drop a breakpoint on `return dataSet.Tables[0];` and inspect the dataSet when you run it in Visual Studio